# Django Queryset Filter (Maybe Needs a Subquery)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to generate a queryset to find mismatches.  As an example

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    car = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    passengers = models.IntegerField()
```

i want to generate a query where i can find cars erroneously listed with two different models.

something along the lines of a query to find that if a car = Wrangler, model = Jeep to find instances of car = Wrangler, model is not Jeep.

Is this possible to do within the ORM, or do i need to use raw SQL?  Someone in #django suggested a subquery, but I am not familiar with how to do this

**Sample Output**
would just be a queryset of mis-matched vehicles (for example car = Wrangler, model = Ford exists for one object but car = Wrangler, model = Jeep for another object).  I was thinking of not having an input just being able to find mismatches.  Does this make sense yet?

Comment: Don't obfuscate your model like that. What are `some car` and `some model`? Foreign keys?

Comment: You should give an example of the expected input and output. It's a bit hard to understand at the moment what exactly do you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you need to model+car be unique together, so you need to find repetitive records first:

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Count

repetitve_cars_list = Vehicle.objects.values('car').annotate(count_car=Count('car')).filter(co
unt_car__gt=1)
```

This will give you the `cars` that was defined with more than one `model`